# Accessing image's metadata with Google Streetview Image API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Google Streetview Image API allows image's metadata JSON query since November 2016. How can I get the `status` from the image URL with Javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by `status` ? Response status?

Comment: Hi, thanks for caring, I found out that it was a simple json parsing mistake on my side. Yes, I was referring to the response Status.

Answer (score 0):

if the "jdata" is your JSON, I think is enough do this:

```
String s = jdata.getString("status");
```